# Butterworth highpass filter, Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to:
Read 'cameraman.tif' and convert it to a double, then filter it with a highpass Butterworth filter (in a frequency domain) , cutoff frequency 40 px and level 5. Binarize (level 0.1, highpass). Find all the pixels 20 px above the closest 'true' pixel. Count the number of isolated territories and their areas. Is it correct?

```
  img = imread('cameraman.tif');
  img = double(img)/255;
  fft = fftshift(fft2(img));
  N = 5; D0 = 40; 
  D = zeros(256); H = zeros(256);

  for kz=1:256
  for kx=1:256
       %Butterworth
       D(kz,kx) = sqrt( (kz-128)^2 + (kx-128)^2);
       H(kz,kx) = 1/(1+(D(kz,kx)/D0)^2*N);
  end
end
filtered = fft.*(1-H);

result = ifft2(ifftshift(filtered));
 figure; subplot(121); imshow(img); title('Oryginalny');
 subplot(122); imshow(result); title('Przefiltrowany');

  binarized = im2bw(real(result), 0.1);

ilosc= bwdist(binarized)>20 ;
ilosc=sum(ilosc(:)) 
figure; imshow(binarized); title('Zbinaryzowany');

w = binarized == 1;
 b = binarized == 0;
 biale = sum(w(:)); 
czarne = sum(b(:));

[blab, blobs] = bwlabel(binarized);
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: no, it works, and it gives me number of pixels, but I'm not sure if the number is correct. I'm pretty sure of filter itself (that part I have done in a past) but I'm new to this bwdist thing :)

Comment: I'm using bwdist only to count pixels which are 20 px above closest 'true' pixel. Is this correct?

Comment: @user3748496 - yes it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your description of what you want to accomplish, your code looks correct.

This does define the Butterworth filter in frequency domain, then the high pass is just subtracting 1 from every coefficient in the low-pass version.  Given your comments, you want to count only those pixels which are approximately 20 pixels above the closest true pixel.  Assuming the Euclidean distance, then this is correct.

Back to your Butterworth filter: Bear in mind that your `for` loops at the beginning to define the filter and the filter centre will change depending on the dimensions of your image.  You'll need to change these if you want to move to another image.

---

If I can make one minor suggestion, I would make the creation of your filter vectorized instead of using `for` loops.  It's actually faster, and you'll notice a huge difference when creating filters of larger sizes.  As such, replace your Butterworth construction code with this:

```
[kx,kz] = meshgrid(1:256, 1:256);
D = sqrt((kz - 128).^2 + (kx - 128).^2);
H = 1 ./ ((1 + (D/D0)).^(2*N));
```

Comment: @user3748496 you're welcome! Please accept my answer if you feel that I helped you.  This can be done by going to the top of my post, looking to the left and clicking on the checkmark button below the up and down arrows.